# How do I scan CD (barcode or cover) to add them to my Spotify favorites?

Tags: cd, spotify

I am setting up Spotify and thought it would be easy to add the CDs I like so as to prime its recommendion system.   For some reason I can't find a way to scan CDs to as to add them as favourites.

(Please tell me if there is a better site to ask this question on)

Comment: You can like any track, you don’t need to scan a CD. Just search for it.

Comment: @cmp I don't wish to have to type in the names of 100s of CDs.

Comment: Contact Spotify. They even have a community where you can ask questions: https://support.spotify.com/us/account_payment_help/account_help/how-can-i-contact-spotify/

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe searching for each album/track is the only way to do it with most streaming services. You don't have to do them all in one day.

Comment: It seems every year someone opens a request for Spotify to add it, and then the request is closed due to not enough voters.